# move text files with specific name using bash on windows machine

Tags: bash

I am trying to move all text files with a specific name in them from one directory to another using `bash` on a windows machine in `cygwin`.  The code is below and but I am not sure how to reference a windows path in bash.  Thank you :).

```
for i in "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\annovar"; do
  mv $i"\"*multianno.txt "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\all""\"basename $i`multianno.txt
done

mv: cannot stat ‘C:\\Users\\cmccabe\\Desktop\\annovar\\*multianno.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `cygpath`, which is a cygwin utility for converting windows to/from cygwin paths.

Without additional arguments it will transform a given windows path to its cygwin equivalent, which is what you want :

```
mv $(cygpath "windows_src") $(cygpath "windows_dst")
```

I wasn't sure it would work with paths containing jokers, but it looks like it does :

> ```
> $ cygpath "C:\path\*a*"
> /cygdrive/c/path/*a*
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't even familiar with `cygpath` :)